# Which Header tags need beheading?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I was looking for a suitable tag for [a question about the email headers my email server creates](https://serverfault.com/questions/759695/why-does-my-server-hostname-appear-in-exim-email-headers-sent-from-a-different-d)  but while looking I noticed that header-related tags could probably do with a clean-up:

[image]

I'm sure there shouldn't be [header](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/header) and [headers](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/headers) as separate tags.
Two people follow [headers](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/headers), so maybe [header](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/header) should be merged into it, but should there be any generic [headers](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/headers) tag at all, is it possible to be an expert on headers in general or is there something more appropriate?

Do we need [host-headers](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/host-headers) and [requestheader](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/requestheader)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These tags are sufficiently generic as to not be all that useful. It's a concept, not a specific technology, and isn't the kind of thing we'd build a tag-community around.

Nor are they common enough to warrant blacklisting, so probably should be periodically gone-through and retagged with more specific items. That said, we could pretty easily alias header -> headers to make them easier to find.

Comment: +1 for making [tag:header] and [tag:headers] a synonym and merging them

Comment: @HBruijn It certainly won't hurt to merge those two tags. Though I still think it remains too generic, and the questions will need to be retagged with more specific tags anyway.

Comment: @kasperd working on it. So far it look like about 70% of them are http-headers questions with the rest smtp-headers. And one outlier involving LUKS headers.

Comment: Is [tag:smtp-headers] actually the correct name for this new tag? I think [tag:mail-headers] would be more accurate, with [tag:smtp-headers] and [tag:mime-headers] as synonyms.

Answer (score 5):

It appears [requestheader](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/requestheader) was intended to be used about a specific configuration option in Apache. But some questions have used [requestheader](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/requestheader) where they should have been using [http-headers](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/http-headers). I saw only 10 questions in total with this tag.

I have created a tag wiki explaining that this tag is for the Apache `RequestHeader` configuration directive. I have removed [requestheader](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/requestheader) from three questions and replaced it with [http-headers](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/http-headers) where appropriate. There are six questions left with the [requestheader](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/requestheader) tag, which all appear to actually be about Apache configuration.

It seems like [host-headers](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/host-headers) is covering one specific HTTP header. I have created a tag wiki explaining this. It looks like the majority of the 26 questions with this tag are using it consistently about the HTTP Host header. It might be useful to rename the tag as [http-host-header](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/http-host-header). I have removed the tag from [a single question](https://serverfault.com/q/331476/214507) about SMTP.

[header](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/header) and [headers](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/headers) seem too generic to be useful. On a quick look it seems like maybe 40-50% of them should be retagged as [http-headers](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/http-headers) while there is also maybe 30-40% about mail headers, and a few which are about other kinds of headers.